# How to close the path

Tags: paperjs

I have a shape that is created using a 'for' loop. The first path has no anchors and therefore is pointy. I'm not sure if that is because it is not closed? Joined? [Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.7/S/dVLRbsIgFP2VmyaLdGrXmfhSR8zi85YlPlofGKVKpNyG0i1G/fdBqaszGU0D997DOQe4p0izSkRZtD4Iy/fRJOJY+PiLGeDScCUoaPENH8zuk1WXIKdcgxuGFbJtMnhO00nI1NhIK1FnsJm5pPu3ub7Euc51UytmByoS96mklEqtUKGhMKqlPoxy3Wljqx1+HiIl9M7uae8oCWGuSzTElyVQSBdueqFho1uPx3Hv0yOwLBvh+CQ8BQQ8wpXFYzjqxoJGUzEFHkapo4TzuV92ewL0OpbhMCi1JekE0vhvObua3Qn73vG+WhJsxE6cvPkLNUwXWBGfmKfxYmAIfmpPDvSGqZMbiBJWFETCA8yg87vsj3BvZRrStwpXFfT3iTvSad2dIbyQ1/i/2lSI7j1PYI+1yGDEma1apaYGq9EESsYtmgzSZA6Xe/lAwBU2oqBgTStct/z2hSM5roUS3A5V/7ke/TSCHTpLTZRttpcf)

```
var circle= new Path.Circle({
    radius: 100,
    position: [200,200]
})

splat= new Path()
splat.fillColor= 'pink'
var count= 5
var length= circle.length
for(var i = 0; i <= count; i++){
    var offset= i / count * length
    const normal = i === 0 || i === count
            ? new Point(0, 0)
            : circle.getNormalAt(offset) * (Math.random() * 50);
        const point = circle.getPointAt(offset).add(i % 2 == 0 ? normal
            : -normal);
            console.log(point)
            splat.add(point)
            splat.smooth({ type: 'catmull-rom', factor: 0.5 });
            
}
splat.fullySelected= true
splat.closed= true
```

Thanks in advance again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call the `smooth()` function once and you have to call it after setting the path to `closed`.

Then another thing that prevent the smoothing to work properly is that your first and last points of the path are the same, remove the last point and it will work as expected.

[Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.7/S/bVJda8IwFP0rl8JoOrWrgi91IsPnjYGP6kOWphpMc0saN0T977tJ/ahjgTbJOTfnnnuTY2R4JaM8WuykE9uoHwks/P6bWxDKCi1hCkb+wCd323QeEHZc2ZUBGpYXat/kMMyy/hWrsVFOoclhOSIY6Lf23DmZ+Ml/Ta256+iylgpwWiqt56jRUkBcK7OLAxkM4d74c8PRDdLSbNyWsNZs2u4DXZIE8zGK6GxC02urQMteL4FbFT4Gy7KRXlvByyXPM3TEfJxA0zgwaCuuQ+R0SsJwOl2W4dg12I9ZWyEq4xh1Iku6ZH61vJHuI2i+OdbaSCg3e/cNt9wUWDEPjLPkj5PaC99LJ52Q6i6T8qJgCp5gBMHp7GL+0cagBR/V0fcSNyzkuFPtFXnZDnHuXN5e68NCaimcLMias3vZuVuhsfkPbypEegZHcIda5hAL7ipSGlis4j6UXDi0OWTpGC6viB7ql5V8F1w0Ub5cn38B)

Comment: Thank you again, it is really appreciated. I called splat.lastSegment.point.remove , hope that is correct.

Comment: You're welcome. About the way to remove the last segment, I would rather remove the last run of the loop (like I did in my example sketch) by using the `i < count` breaking condition. Otherwise, if you want to remove a segment, the `remove()` method has to be called on the segment, not on the point. Ps: could you accept my answers so that the issues are marked as resolved ? thanks.